# Using Regex to match the middle of a path?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a var `showNo` that's an input for the beginning of a directory.

example: `var showNo = "101B"`

After `showNo` are characters that include spaces and other junk set up on the network set by another department.

example: `/101B A Trip to the Beach/`

I need to use sub directories inside of this one:

example: `/101B A Trip to the Beach/assets/tools/`

Is there a way to use regex and the variable to avoid scanning all of the directories and trying to match a substring of the first 4 characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var directory = str.match(/\/101B[^\/]+\//)[0];
```

Will match to the first directory name that starts with you variable.

More importantly the idea is as follows :

1. Match the first four character string literal that starts with a directory slash.
2. Then match any character **that is not** a directory slash. The "is not" is indicated by the ^.
3. Then repeat 2 an additional 0 or more times.
4. Finally match the directory slash.

I suspect you had trouble with the "anything that is NOT" character class. It is sometimes tricky but once you get it it is a very useful short cut.

--edit--

Actually on re reading I suspect you had trouble with using the variable inside the regex, correct?
That's easy enough, too, once you know how.

You can construct it as a string first:

```
var regex_string = "/" + showNo + "[^/]+/";
```

And then "compile" it into a regex which you can use as normally :

```
var regex_dir = RegExp(regex_string);

var directory = str.match(regex_dir);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the Edit Paul but I want to keep my hope this helps.

Comment: I think you mean `str.match(/\/101B[^\/]+\//)` for your first. Or as the `/` don't need to be escaped if not using a regex literal, you could simply do: `str.match('/' + showNo + '[^/]+/')`.